# Redirect to community builder page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, partner-communities

We are working on a custom login experience for our partner users where we want to redirect them to a certain community builder page after login.
=> goal of this page is to allow the partner user to select for which Account he will work so the visibility of certain elements in the community is related to that chosen account.

Edit: rephrased question: How can I get the URL (page reference) of a custom community builder page. Visualforce pages use the syntax Page.SomeRandomName. Does the same syntax exist for community builder pages or should I hardcode it?

Comment: Have you checked [login flows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_associate.htm)?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a lightning component, however, this would involve having a server side conotroller (apex) to check for the users profile (make sure they are a partner), then, the redirection would take place in your client side controller once you have validated the users profile, using [force:navigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm)

Comment: But how do I know the URL? The only way is to hard code it? Or is there a syntax similar to Page.VFpageNamr for community builder pages?

Comment: its not clear how/what page you want your users to be redirected to, will you give them a choice? or will it always be to a specific page? either way, you can build a relative path in your client side controller. Maybe you can open a new post with how and what it is you are attempting (code wise that is)

Comment: This is explained in my question. After login we show a page where the user can select the client he wants to work for. But actually it does not really matter which page it is. I just want to redirect to A custom community builder page after login...